# Is it possible to convert a GUID value into a DWORD?

Tags: mfc, guid

I have seen how to convert a `GUID` into a `CString` but what about a `DWORD`.

Possible?

Comment: A `GUID` is 16 bytes. A `DWORD` is 4. So no.

Comment: Sure, that's possible. Is it possible to convert 16 bytes of information into 4 bytes of information, without losing any information? Highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UUID/GUID is 128 bits. A DWORD is only 32 bits. If by "convert" you mean "convert without losing data", then the answer is no.